# Haskell: attempting to desugar simple State monad get and put

Tags: haskell, get, put, state-monad

To study the details of the State monad, I'm trying to create myself a complete desugared version of a simple state monad function, completing the thought started in [How does 'get' actually /get/ the initial state in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036957/how-does-get-actually-get-the-initial-state-in-haskell), in the answer by J Cooper.

The example state monad function simply swaps the state and the input value, so that (conceptually) if the input is (v, s) then the output is (s, v).  I show three translations, first from do notation to desugared >>= and >>, then placing those operators in function position, and finally attempting to replace them and get/put with their definitions.

The 'do' version and the first two translations work, but the final translation does not.  Problems:

1. Upon loading the module, GHCi reports that z1 is not in scope.
2. I've not figured out exactly how to represent omitting the argument passing in the >> translation.

How should these be fixed?

FWIW, current Haskell platform (GHC 7.4.2).

Thanks!

```
-- simpleswap

import Control.Monad.State

-- =============================================
-- 'Do' version
simpleswap1 :: String -> State String String
simpleswap1 inp = do
    z1 <- get
    put inp
    return z1

-- =============================================
-- Desugared to >>= and >>
simpleswap2 :: String -> State String String
simpleswap2 inp = 
    get >>= 
    \z1 -> put inp >>
    return z1 

-- =============================================
-- >>= and >> changed to function position
simpleswap3 :: String -> State String String
simpleswap3 inp = 
    (>>=) get 
    (\z1 -> (>>) (put inp)  (return z1) )


-- =============================================
-- Attempt to translate >>=, >>, get and put

simpleswap4 :: String -> State String String
simpleswap4 inp = 
    state $ \s1 -> 
        -- (>>=) 
        let (a2, s2) = runState ( {- get -}  state $ \sg -> (sg,sg) ) s1
        in  runState (rhs1 a2) s2
        where 
            rhs1 a2 = \z1 -> 
            -- (>>)
                state $ \s3 -> 
                    let (a4, s4) = runState ( {- put inp -}  state $ \_ -> (inp, ()) ) s3
                    in runState (rhs2 a4) s4
                    where
                        rhs2 a4 = return z1

-- =============================================
main = do
    putStrLn "version 1004"
    let v = "vvv"
    let s  = "sss"
    putStrLn ("Before val: " ++ v ++ "  state: " ++ s)    
    let (v2, s2) = runState (simpleswap4 v) s
    putStrLn ("After val: " ++ v2 ++ "  state: " ++ s2)

-- =============================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few minor mistakes in `simpleswap4`. Here is a corrected version:

```
simpleswap4 :: String -> State String String
simpleswap4 inp = 
    state $ \s1 -> 
        -- (>>=) 
        let (z1, s2) = runState ( {- get -}  state $ \sg -> (sg,sg) ) s1
        in  runState (rhs1 z1) s2
        where 
            rhs1 z1 = 
            -- (>>)
                state $ \s3 -> 
                    let (_, s4) = runState ( {- put inp -}  state $ \_ -> ((), inp) ) s3
                    in runState rhs2 s4
                    where
                        rhs2 = return z1
```

I've renamed `a2` to `z1` (in lines 5 and 6). This doesn't change the semantics, but emphasized that the first component of the pair returned by the desugared `get` call is actually the result that gets bound to `z1` in the previous versions of `simpleswap`.

The type of `rhs1` should be `String -> State String String`. In your version, it gets an additional lambda-bound variable. It's unclear what the difference between `a2` and `z1` should be in your version. Removing the lambda (in line 8) also has the advantage of fixing your scoping problem. You are using `z1` in the nested `where`-clause, but the `where` can only see variables bound on the left hand side of the declaration it is attached to.

In line 11, I've replaced `a4` with `_`. This is to emphasize that `(>>)` does discard the result of the first action. As a consequence, `rhs2` is not parameterized over this result either.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much for correcting my attempt, and for detailing the changes.  Much appreciated!